# How to force Firefox to save degree symbol using single-byte encoding?

Tags: php, html, firefox, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have this code (degree symbol encoded as HTML):

```html
<a download="text.txt" href="data:text/plain,&deg;">Download degree symbol</a>
```

What I do

1. Click the link
2. Save the file
3. Open it in TextPad
4. **Problem:** I see `Â°`, instead of the expected `°` (When I do a hex dump I get `b0c2`)

How do I fix this?

My context is I have a PHP-encoded `$string = "&deg;"`. but for purposes of this example I stripped it down and inserted degree into HTML link directly.  I tried using `utf8_decode()` with same results as above.

I need to open the resulting file in a legacy Windows application that seems to read ASCII only (aka displays `Â°` like above and I need to only have it display the degree symbol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of ... cor-el of Mozilla Support, use this:

```
data&colon;text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1,%b0
```